# How to make Eclipse use autocompletion according to referred schema

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

Im trying to create a schema for an xml document for autocompletion in Eclipse, but I cant find any tutorials on how to do it. I have created an xsd file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

but when trying to create the xml document, there is no autocomplete. My xml doc begins with

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="C:/root/to/namespace/dir
         C:/root/to/namespace/dir/namespace.xsd">
```

Comment: Autocomplete would be a function of the tool you're using, not an intrisic part of XML or XSD.  Please specify the tool in which you're looking to get autocomplete working.

Comment: Also, read up on how to use xsi:schemaLocation: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-loc